# missing partial when putting a model in another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, nested-forms

I have never seen an error like this, so I don't even know what information of my app to share with you. I am putting an 'address' model inside a 'customer model'. Here is the error. (edit)I am using [SprintApp](https://github.com/macfanatic/SprintApp) as a guide for my app. They too also have a addess model, and their clients model is my customers model.

> 

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Admin/customers#new
  Showing /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/active_admin-fa7e4de2d5fa/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb where line #1 raised:
Missing partial admin/customers/form, active_admin/resource/form, active_admin/base/form, inherited_resources/base/form, application/form with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :arb, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/danielhatcher/rails/print/app/views"
  * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/active_admin-fa7e4de2d5fa/app/views"
  * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/kaminari-0.14.1/app/views"
  * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-2.2.3/app/views"
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: insert_tag renderer_for(:new)
Rails.root: /Users/danielhatcher/rails/print

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
```

I know its hard to ask for an answer without showing my code, but we can atleast start the dialogue and i can edit and add whats needed. Thanks in advance.

customers controller

```
    ActiveAdmin.register Customer do
    # Menu item
  menu :label => "Customers", :parent => "Administration"
      index do
        column :name
      end

    form :partial => "form"

  show :title => :name do
      panel "Client Details" do
          attributes_table_for resource do
            row :name
            row :email
            row :phone
            row :created_at do
              resource.created_at.humanize
            end
            row :updated_at do
              resource.updated_at.humanize
            end
          end
        text_node(render :partial => "addresses/show", :locals => { :address => resource.address })
      end
    end
end
```

Customers _form

```
    <%=
semantic_form_for @customer, :builder => ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder do |f| 
  f.inputs "Customer Information" do 
    f.input :name 
        f.input :email
        f.input :phone
  render :partial => "addresses/form", :locals => { :form => f } 
  f.buttons 
end 
%>
```

Addresses _form

```
<%=
form.inputs "Address" do 
  form.semantic_fields_for :address do |address| 
    address.inputs :class => "" do 
      address.input :street 
      address.input :city 
      address.input :state, :as => :select, :collection => States::all.invert 
      address.input :zip, as: :string
    end 
  end 
end 
%>
```

Comment: How does your app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb look like?

Comment: my file structure stops at app/views/active_admin. I have nothing after this, yet. I have been following an open source project to give myself a guide and their code doesn't have a file like that there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say you're putting an 'address' model inside of the 'customer' model, I'm assuming you mean the form, which I'm assuming means that you're placing two forms in the same view?

Either way, we'd need what view you are trying to display, as well as the invoking controller. My initial guess is that you're namespacing- something like `Admin::CustomersController`, but you haven't run generators to generate views from `active_admin`.

Never used [active_admin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin), but as per the docs, have you tried running the following?

```
rails generate active_admin:assets
```

Comment: Yes i am talking about a form. When i ran rails g active_admin:assets the terminal said idetical, so i'm assuming they were already there.

Comment: What does your tree structure look like? e.g. what files are under admin/

Answer (score 1):

Check the [same error](https://github.com/macfanatic/SprintApp/issues/1) as indicated by `Kwent` and the solutions as follows:

Also see the following error:

> Missing partial admin/customers/form, active_admin/resource/form,
>   active_admin/base/form, inherited_resources/base/form,
>   application/form with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html],
>   :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :arb, :coffee, :haml]}.

The error also indicates that you are missing a partial as listed in the error log.

**For example:**

The partial file `_form.html.erb` should be in `app/views/admin/customers` folder.
Same is for others.

Then you should render your partial like: `<%= render :partial => "form" %>` in your controller.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I read over the error for kwent and that did not seem to work.